# Regex for extracting certain information from a string

Tags: pandas, string, pyspark, substring

Below is the string that I have -

```
vdp_plus_forecast_aucc_VDP_20221024_variance_analysis_20221107_backcasting_actuals_asp_True_vlt_True.csv
```

I need RegEx to take out following items from the string -

```
20221107
vlt_True
```

Need help with writing right RegEx for these two extractions. I'm performing the operation on a PySpark DF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the answer is based on the variable in front of it so it's capturing the value of variance analysis:

`(?<=_variance_analysis_)[0-9]+|vlt_(True|False)`

This should capture the variables you wanted, if you only need the value of vlt, you can replace `vlt_` with `(?<=_vlt)` which will just capture the value without the variable